# Why does Lauren Ψ have 7 rep?

Tags: discussion

Bear with my curiosity here - with no questions or answers, where did Lauren's 7 rep come from, and why?

Comment: It's not a real 7 rep; it's a mystical 7 rep to match her mystical *psi*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going by [this comment](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/95?m=1460339#1460339) left by a fellow mod in chat, her first three edits had to be peer-reviewed (for whatever reason). That's 3×2 = 6 points, plus the one everyone starts with, makes 7. Now Lauren seems to have the full edit privileges. No peer reviews, no points.

Comment: I assume it's the same with the diamond Community mod, with 3 rep?

Comment: @drm65: The Community user owns a whole bunch of stuff, including, if I am not lying, all votes on deleted posts. In any case, reverse-engineering its rep is considerably more complicated.

Comment: @Reg: I *hope* you meant 'if I'm not mistaken.' "If I'm not lying" raises too many metaphysical questions for a Friday night.

Comment: @Tim: Speakers of a certain language will appreciate the reference. Others I am comfortable with leaving scratching their heads. That's how I roll, *especially* on Friday nights. (^_^)

Answer (score 5):

The 7 rep is incalculable. It's a direct result of raw [CHAOS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100137/164286) being unleashed upon SE.

Answer (score 0):

It is probable that her first edits needed to be peer-reviewed because she was not a moderator, when she edited those first questions. Watching at her profile now, I see that now she is not shown as moderator, on EL&U.